# Logging into a website?( Jsoup)

Tags: java, jsoup

What is required to log into a website using Jsoup? I believe my code is correct, but I have never successfully logged into a website using Jsoup so I might be missing something. Here is my code:

```
 try {                                            
        String url = ("http://quadrigacx.com/login");


        Connection.Response loginForm = (Connection.Response)Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();





        Document loginDoc = loginForm.parse();


        Elements loginElements = loginDoc.select("input:not([name=client_id]):not([name=password])");

        int i = 0;

        String v[] = new String[loginElements.size()];

        for (Element element: loginElements){
            v[i++] = element.attr("value");
        }


        int ii = 0;

        String n[] = new String[loginElements.size()];

        for (Element element: loginElements){
            n[ii++] = element.attr("name");
        }


         Connection.Response loginFormLogin = (Connection.Response)Jsoup.connect(url)
                 .cookies(loginForm.cookies())          
                .data(n[0],v[0])
                 .data("client_id", "xxxxxxx")
                 .data("password", "xxxxxx")
                .data(n[1],v[1])
                .data(n[2],v[2])
                 .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                 .execute();


         Document document2 = Jsoup.connect("http://quadrigacx.com/settings")
            .cookies(loginFormLogin.cookies())
            .get();
        System.out.print(document2.toString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

`document2` returns a login page which shows it didn't successfully log in. There is a input value named `time`, and I think that it might be why it doesn't work. It is a value that goes up over time;  I ran the code twice and the time variables returned `1511226860` and `1511226876`. My code takes about 10 seconds to print the doc, so maybe the `time` variable has already changed by the time it sends the post request? I am not sure whether this is the problem. Maybe there is something else I'm not seeing? Thanks.

Edit: Here is the code, I post the authenticate after I have already logged in with the user Id and password. `loginCookies` are the cookies from the first login.  `Connection.Response auth = Jsoup.connect("https://quadrigacx.com/authenticate")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla")
                        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                        .cookies(loginCookies)
                        .data("google_code", googleCode.getText())
                        .data("email_code", emailCode.getText())
                        .data("authenticate", "Authenticate")
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .execute();`
***I have also tried:*** 
                                                                            `byte[] gcText = googleCode.getText().getBytes(ISO_8859_1); 
                String gcValue = new String(gcText, UTF_8); 
                byte[] ecText = emailCode.getText().getBytes(ISO_8859_1); 
                String ecValue = new String(ecText, UTF_8); 
                Connection.Response auth = Jsoup.connect("https://quadrigacx.com/authenticate")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla")
                        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                        .cookies(loginCookies)
                        .data("google_code", gcValue)
                        .data("email_code", ecValue)
                        .data("authenticate", "Authenticate")
                        .followRedirects(true)
                        .execute();`

Comment: The password is not being sent "as-is" to the server. Open the dev-tools of the browser and you'll see that it is hashed/encrypted in some way, so you'll have to do some reversing to figure the proccess and imitate it. I would start with the scripts named SHA256 and QCX. Another option is to check wheater the site has an API.

Comment: I did not find the namedcalled SHA256, but I found this  `$(document).ready(function(){
       
            if (clientId && pword)
                $('#password').val(QCX.security.hash(clientId, pword));
            else return false; `  in the submit script, does that mean the client id is also hashed?

Comment: @TDG In a case like this, I think it would be easier if I were able to log in manually on my browser, and then copy the cookies + userAgent into my program and start from there. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add more parameters to your request:
**csrf, time, hash**

Code with empty TABLE:

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quadrigacx {
    public static String[] TABLE = new String[]{}; // Add data here

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        final String URL = "https://www.quadrigacx.com/login/";
        String password = "password";
        String clientId = "id";

        String hashPassword = getHash(new String[]{clientId, password});

        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        Element csrf = response.parse().select("input[name=csrf]").first();
        Element time = response.parse().select("input[name=time]").first();
        Element hash = response.parse().select("input[name=hash]").first();

        Jsoup.connect(URL)
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .data("password", hashPassword)
                .data("client_id", clientId)
                .data("csrf", csrf.attr("value"))
                .data("time", time.attr("value"))
                .data("hash", hash.attr("value"))
                .execute();

        String googleCode = "";

        while (!googleCode.matches("^(?=[0-9]+)\\d{6}$")) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the Two-Factor Authentication to validate your login. (Numbers Only): ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            googleCode = in.nextLine();
        }

        Jsoup.connect("https://www.quadrigacx.com/authenticate")
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .data("google_code", googleCode)
                .data("redirect", "dash")
                .data("authenticate", "Authenticate")
                .execute();

        response = Jsoup.connect("https://www.quadrigacx.com/dash/")
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        System.out.println(response.body());

    }

    private static String getHash(String[] loginArray) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder h = new StringBuilder();
        for (String data : loginArray)
            h.append(data).append(getSalt(data));

        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] byteHash = digest.digest(h.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(byteHash.length * 2);
        for (byte b : byteHash)
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String getSalt(String arg) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return TABLE[getLastByte(arg)];
    }

    private static int getLastByte(String login) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final byte[] utf8Bytes = login.getBytes("UTF-8");
        return utf8Bytes[utf8Bytes.length - 1];
    }
}
```

**Full working code you can find here (very long):**

https://pastebin.com/aBf1M3fX

Comment: Thanks for the code it is working nice, now I am trying to log in using their "Two-Factor Authentication" service. I did some digging and found this `<form action="https://www.quadrigacx.com/authenticate" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> ` Does this mean I have to convert the google and email codes to utf 8? I'll update my code my code so you can see.

Comment: Thanks for the help, may I ask what `!gCode.matches("^(?=[0-9]+)\\d{6}$")` means? I would like to have a better understanding in case I can use the same method for getting the emailCode aswell. Thanks!

Comment: I did some research and I am guessing it means "if the code is not 6 digit long and contains number from 1-9". I have another question though, can the input values for emailCode and googleCode be passed just as strings or do I have to do some utf-8 conversion kind of like what you did for the password field?