# Logging into and retrieving data from a website using a "post" request on JSoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am trying to create an App that logs into my schoool's grade servers and displays data. The website I am trying to log into is: "https://portal.mcpsmd.org/public/"

I have written my code according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403851/logging-into-a-website-jsoup) stackoverflow question. Here is the relevant code for my specific situation:

```
 Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://portal.mcpsmd.org/public/")
                        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                        .execute();

 Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://portal.mcpsmd.org/guardian/home.html/")
                        .data("account", "#######")
                        .data("pw","*******")
                        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                        .post();

System.out.println(document.title());
```

The reason I have written my code this way is because when I did "inspect element" on my school's page I saw this:

[screenshot of school's inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRMSW.png)

I can see that my school uses the method "post" and the login request is at "/guardian/home.html"

Many of the Stack Overflow questions I have looked at has told me to use a method like this, where I connect to the login request and send it my username and password as data. Am I going about this correctly at all? I am trying to use JSoup to login to my school's website, so in my mind if I do "document.title()" it should print the name of the page I get once already signing in. This program is only printing the name of the log-in screen page.

I have been working on this project for almost two days now, and initially started with 0 knowledge of JSoup. I would greatly appreciate any explanation on the best way to go about logging into a website using JSoup.

Comment: Look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871801/problems-submitting-a-login-form-with-jsoup/31877829#31877829

Comment: How would I go about determining what values my site requires in order to login?

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools to inspect the traffic to the site.